# How do you repeatedly add a specific value to a variable in a loop?

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a program where I am adding 0.165 to the variable `weight`. I am trying to repeat this 15 times. However, it is crucial that `weight` is constantly being added to 0.165 15 times, e.g. 13.365, 13.53, 13.495, etc.

How would I accomplish this? Sorry, I am kind of new to this whole python coding, so please point out any excess mistakes from my code.

```
   weight=int(input("Enter your weight"))
   newweight=weight+1
   othernewweight=newweight*0.165
   count=['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15']
   for x in range(0,15):
       print("year", count+0", "othernewweight+0.65")
```

Comment: Put `weight += 0.165` as the first line in your loop? Won't change your behavior since you never use `weight` after the second line, but that would do what you ask. I have no idea what you actual goal here is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will ask you for input `weight` in `float` type, then repeat 0.165 addition to `weight` for 15 times

```
weight=float(input("Enter your weight"))

for x in range(15):
    weight += 0.165
    print (round(weight,3)) #to print 3 decimals
```

Output :

```
Enter your weight 13.2                                                                                                                                                              
13.365                                                                                                                                                                             
13.53                                                                                                                                                                              
13.695                                                                                                                                                                             
13.86                                                                                                                                                                              
14.025                                                                                                                                                                             
14.19                                                                                                                                                                              
14.355                                                                                                                                                                             
14.52                                                                                                                                                                              
14.685
14.85                                                                                                                                                                              
15.015                                                                                                                                                                             
15.18                                                                                                                                                                              
15.345                                                                                                                                                                             
15.51                                                                                                                                                                              
15.675
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, however, is it possible to use print (round(weight,3)) in every, kind of code?

Comment: @Callmedell of course you can. But that `print()` syntax is for python3. If you use python2, use `print round(weight,3)`

Answer (score 2):

There are a few problems here. First, you have put `count + 0` and `othernewweight+0.65` inside of quotes, so they are printed as text, literally "othernewweight+0.65", instead of the values you are looking for. You also need to make sure you are actually updating the variable. `weight+0.165` doesn't do anything unless you store it somewhere as `weight=weight+0.165` or `weight += 0.165` for short.

```
weight=int(input("Enter your weight"))
for x in range(15):
    weight += 0.165
    print(weight)
```

Comment: Alright, thank you for clarifying my mistakes. However, is it possible to multiply the inputted variable by any value, and then add 0.165 15 times to it after?

Comment: Sorry, but how would I add for example "Year 1, 13.365 , then Year 2, 13.53"?  Please forgive my ignorance.

Comment: Yes, to multiply just once, before the line `for x in range(15)`, put `mulitplier = 2` and then `weight *= multiplier` where 2 is the number (or variable name) you want to multiply by.

Comment: To print out a combination of strings and variables, use a python fstring (python 3.6 and higher). `print(f"Year {x+1}, {weight}")` will do it. Hope that helps Dell.